# Why doesn't it work? Windows, using process.h

Tags: c, windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

void sayit(void * arg) {

    printf("hello, world! from child process\n");
    _endthread();

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    if (_beginthread(sayit, 16, NULL) == -1)
        printf("Error\n");

    return 0;
}
```

By idea program must print string in function `sayit` but it doesn't happen.
Is there any functions to determine had process completed or it still working?
Can you give me links to full documentation for process.h?

Comment: Does it compile? If not, what are errors?

Comment: Please post the error message

Answer (score 1):

You spawn a thread but you don't wait for it. So high chance that the program ends before the second thread is resumed. Use _beginthreadex and WaitForSingleObject or Boost.Threads which have a 'join' function.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a thread in a non-suspended state there is no guarantee when the thread will start so it may just be that the program ends before the thread has started or just as the thread is starting.

In order to make sure the thread runs you need to do something like

```
unsigned threadID = 0;
HANDLE hd = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, sayit, NULL, 0, &threadID);
WaitForSingleObject( hd, INFINITE ); // this will wait for thread to end
CloseHandle(hd);
```

Comment: i agree, better would have been a uint32_t or something, after all they use such as return value ;-)